# Is there a shortcut for typing this.x = x in java while constructing an object?

Tags: java, this, shortcut

When I am storing a parameter (or is it an argument?) to a private instance variable of a class, is there is quicker way to write `this.x = x` (where x is the argument of the constructor and `this.x` is the instance variable)? Sometimes with longer variable names I find it a little repetitive, is there anything like `x++;` etc?

I am new to Java so let me know if I can make anything more clear.

Comment: no - but if you an IDE, it shouldn't be a problem. try IntelliJ.

Comment: That's an odd thing to want to optimize, it's not a terribly common situation.

Comment: @Cubic really?  It's pretty common for value types to have constructors that just write the parameters to instance variables.

Comment: @dimo414 Sure, but do you spend all day writing new value classes?

Comment: @Cubic I get you're point, but in truth I probably would if it weren't for tools like `auto/value` and protocol buffers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. I'm not sure what you mean by `x++` -- that's the postfix increment operator -- but the only way to assign variables is, well, to assign them.

For example:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double gradePointAverage;

    public Student(String name, int age, double gradePointAverage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gradePointAverage = gradePointAverage;
    }
}
```

Most IDE's will have a shortcut to auto-generate a constructor for you. For example, IntelliJ allows you to type alt+insert which will show a context menu allowing you to auto-generate constructors, getters, and setters.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I had no idea IDEs could auto generate the constructors. When I use this feature, `super();` is automatically added to the constructor. Could you explain to me why it adds this?

Comment: @mover96 `super()` calls the parent constructor. If your class extends another class, this does the initialization defined in the parent constructor. If your class is a standalone, like the one I have in my example, then `super()` is calling the constructor on `java.lang.Object` which is, as far as I'm aware, a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can do this using a IDE for helping you. Try [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) or [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Using an IDE, you can [Eclipse: Create Getters and Setters](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-gettersetter.htm) or [IntelliJ: Generating Getters and Setters](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-getters-and-setters.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in an easier way.  If you want avoid doing it you can put a '1' or a '2' after the field names or the parameter variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking no, there's no syntactic shorthand.  However there are ways to avoid needing to do this.  In particular, I'm a big fan of [`auto/value`](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value), a project that lets you define [value types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type) with minimal boiler-plate, e.g.:

```
@AutoValue
abstract static class Animal {
  static Animal create(String name, int numberOfLegs) {
    return new AutoValue_Animal(name, numberOfLegs);
  }
  abstract String name();
  abstract int numberOfLegs();
}
```

Since `auto/value` takes advantage of [annotation processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation#Processing), it's not a good solution for small programs that aren't using Maven or Ant, but presumably for small projects you won't mind the mild `this.x = x;` redundancy.